# How to style a ul list so at a breakpoint two li elements are in a column?

Tags: html, css

[This is how it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ricjN.png)

[This is how I need it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri0xJ.png)

I simply need to change they layout of the links at a breakpoint, but I have no idea how to do it. I am starting to think that the only possible way is to use grids, but I was wondering if it is possible to do it with flex.

HTML:

```
          <li class="contact__location">San Francisco</li>
          <li class="contact__link">
            <a href="https://github.blog">https://github.blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="contact__twitter">Not Available</li>
          <li class="contact__company">@github</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
  @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-tablet) {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  li {
    font-family: "Space Mono";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;

    color: #4b6a9b;
```

Comment: Set the flex-basis (or general flex properties) on each li element. For half width, use `flex: 0 0 50%`, for a quarter `flex: 0 0 25%` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```css
 li {
    font-family: "Space Mono";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;

   color: #4b6a9b;
}

ul {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <ul class='left'>  
      <li class="contact__location">San Francisco</li>
      <li class="contact__link">
              <a href="https://github.blog">https://github.blog</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='right'>
      <li class="contact__twitter">Not Available</li>
      <li class="contact__company">@github</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```